# Compilation error on generic type argument in sealed class permits clause

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have an abstract class (a phantom type) with 2 nested classes (phantom types as well) to form ADT:

```java
public sealed abstract class APath<R> permits APath<R>.LastWildcard<R>, APath<R>.WholeWildcard<R> {
    ....

    protected final List<ADir> dirs;

    public final class LastWildcard<R1> extends APath<R1> {
        ...
    }

    public final class WholeWildcard<R1> extends APath<R1> {
        ...
    }
}
```

and `ADir` is (ADT too):

```java
public sealed abstract class ADir permits ADir.Wildcard, ADir.Dir {
    public final class Wildcard extends ADir {}
    public final class Dir extends ADir {}
}
```

previously `ADir` was an interface, but due to this strange error I tried to change it to an abstract class. So, Eclipse and VSCode (with appropriate java extensions which is based on the Eclipse LSP as I know) don't show errors.

But Maven prints errors:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project prefile: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:                                                                                                 
[ERROR] /D:/Experiment/src/main/java/prefile/pref/APath.java:[13,52] '{' expected                                            
[ERROR] /D:/Experiment/src/main/java/prefile/pref/APath.java:[15,25] class, interface, enum, or record expected              
[ERROR] /D:/Experiment/src/main/java/prefile/pref/APath.java:[17,9] class, interface, enum, or record expected               
[ERROR] /D:/Experiment/src/main/java/prefile/pref/APath.java:[20,17] class, interface, enum, or record expected              
[ERROR] /D:/Experiment/src/main/java/prefile/pref/APath.java:[22,17] class, interface, enum, or record expected              
[ERROR] /D:/Experiment/src/main/java/prefile/pref/APath.java:[25,16] class, interface, enum, or record expected              
[ERROR] /D:/Experiment/src/main/java/prefile/pref/APath.java:[27,9] class, interface, enum, or record expected               
[ERROR] /D:/Experiment/src/main/java/prefile/pref/APath.java:[29,16] class, interface, enum, or record expected              
[ERROR] /D:/Experiment/src/main/java/prefile/pref/APath.java:[33,9] class, interface, enum, or record expected               
[ERROR] /D:/Experiment/src/main/java/prefile/pref/APath.java:[35,16] class, interface, enum, or record expected              
[ERROR] /D:/Experiment/src/main/java/prefile/pref/APath.java:[38,17] class, interface, enum, or record expected              
[ERROR] /D:/Experiment/src/main/java/prefile/pref/APath.java:[40,9] class, interface, enum, or record expected               
[ERROR] /D:/Experiment/src/main/java/prefile/pref/APath.java:[42,16] class, interface, enum, or record expected              
[ERROR] /D:/Experiment/src/main/java/prefile/pref/APath.java:[44,17] class, interface, enum, or record expected              
[ERROR] /D:/Experiment/src/main/java/prefile/pref/APath.java:[45,9] class, interface, enum, or record expected               
[ERROR] /D:/Experiment/src/main/java/prefile/pref/APath.java:[47,25] class, interface, enum, or record expected              
...
```

The location of the first error is here:

```
public sealed abstract class APath<R> permits APath<R>.LastWildcard<R>, APath<R>.WholeWildcard<R> 
                                                   ^  HERE !!!
```

My `pom.xml` is:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>XXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>XXX</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>XXX</name>
    <description>XXX</description>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <exec.mainClass>XXX</exec.mainClass>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
            <version>1.82</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And it seems that VSCode (and Eclipse) (at least I think so :) use the same Java (the same JDK). What can be the reason of the errors? Is it really wrong/unsupported syntax? Maybe 17 version is not enough? I have no idea TBH. Any hints and assumptions please.

Comment: Eclipse has its own compiler (called "ecj") and doesn't use javac, the two compilers occasionally disagree about what is valid - usually generics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can be the reason of the errors? Is it really wrong/unsupported syntax?

Yes. According to the Java language specification, the permits clause of a class is a list of [type names](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-6.html#jls-TypeName) not [class types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-4.html#jls-ClassType) (as `extends`/`implements`). See [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-8.html#jls-ClassPermits). A type name is just the name of a class without any generic type arguments.

In other words, drop the generic type arguments:

```
public sealed abstract class APath<R> permits APath.LastWildcard, APath.WholeWildcard {
    ....

    protected final List<ADir> dirs;

    public final class LastWildcard<R1> extends APath<R1> {
        ...
    }

    public final class WholeWildcard<R1> extends APath<R1> {
        ...
    }
}
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, Eclipse (and the VSCode plugin) use a different java compiler than Maven. The former uses `ejc` and the latter uses `javac` which comes with the JDK itself.

That could explain the discrepancy in the errors. It seems like the `ecj` compiler doesn't implement this part of the language specification correctly.

Comment: Oh, it helped! Maven passed. But I added them because without them I see warning in VSCode/Eclipse "APath.LastWildcard is a raw type. References to generic type APath<R>.LastWildcard<R1> should be parameterized

Comment: @RandomB yeah, it seems like the eclipse java compiler doesn't implement this part of the language specification correctly.

Comment: I think there is a pending bug report for Eclipse about this.

Comment: It's interesting, but I don't see the same warning in Netbeans (I've turned on all Java standard warnings), which means that Netbeans uses my installed javac, not some bound/embedded one.